# how to create a buffer like a fugitive temporary buffer

Tags: buffers, plugin-fugitive, scratch-buffer

When we call `:Gdiff` on a file, fugitive will create a buffer with a name `fugitive:///path/to/file/`. The `modifiable` option is off and `readonly` option is on. Most importantly, the file does not exist on the disk so that the function `filereadonly(FILENAME)` returns false. How to setup such a temporary file?

Comment: I don't think `filereadonly()` is a Vim function. Did you mean `filereadable()`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a buffer like this with the `'buftype'` option:

```
:set buftype=nofile
```

As [`:help 'buftype'`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27buftype%27) explains:

```
The value of this option specifies the type of a buffer:

  <empty>       normal buffer
  nofile        buffer which is not related to a file and will not be
                written
```

See `:help special-buffers` for more background on this and other, related, options.

N.B. As far as I can tell, the fugitive plugin doesn't actually set this value of `'buftype'` anywhere. It does use `buftype=nowrite` in a few places but not, for me, in the `:Gdiff` buffer. (But then, for me, it also doesn't set `'nomodifiable'` or `'readonly'` as you describe in your question, so possibly you're just using a different version.)